# PHP changes my SQLite3 charset encoding

Tags: php, utf-8, sqlite, character-encoding

I have some piece of software which generates a text-only SQLite3 DB, another one which performs some operations on said DB and in the end there is a PHP interface I use for a demo (and so it will be removed as soon as the demo ends) which performs some `SELECT`s and shows part of the data.

Everything is ok and working until the PHP connects to the DB (I double-checked at every step), at which point the charset encoding is messed up in the DB, not only in the visualization. Both PHP and the DB use utf-8 as the charset and I've tried to connect to the DB using the `SQLITE3_OPEN_READONLY` flag but nevertheless when I open the DB I find the charset messed up. Am I missing some parameter in PHP? Please note that the PHP code is only part of a demo and will not be released with the software, so I can change anything in the PHP but nothing in the previous steps.

Comment: How exactly are you opening the database?

Comment: I use the SQLite3 constructor